# xcode error: ...this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ibShadowedLargeTitleTextAttributes

Tags: swift, xcode, runtime-error, key-value, nsunknownkeyexception

I keep getting this error. The app worked before I used a color set.

The error says something about `ibShadowedLargeTitleTextAttributes`. I dont have any color set for the large title shadow, I am using the default (clear). I restarted Xcode, used a color for the shadow, removed it again. The error keeps showing up when I want to run it, but the built succeeds.

The full error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<UINavigationBar 0x10650fd10> valueForUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the 
key ibShadowedLargeTitleTextAttributes.'
```

Edit: The App is working when I choose another color for the title text (one that is not part of the color set). This is very strange since I use the exact same color for other text in the app. It is a color I made in a color set. I made a new color in the color set, it is also not working. I have to use a standard color or choose one from the standard color window.

Comment: I have the same issue when I set the color of the large title to a named color thats in my assets catalog. This seems to be some kind of bug from Apples side. Im in the process of writing them a bug report right now.

Comment: @Naknut do you have a rdar link for the bug report you submitted?

Comment: I removed the named colors in the navigation bar and the issue was resolved.

Comment: make sure your IBOutlets are set correctly

Comment: @Naknut have you filed this bug yet?

Comment: @Naknut Did you end up filing a radar?

Comment: This started happening to me a lot in the iOS 13 Betas, in Xcode 11. This was an older app and I made the switch to colors in the Asset library to support dark mode. The weird thing is that it doesn't crash my app consistently - sometimes it actually works. Then it will crash repeatedly, and some combination of restarting/resetting the Simulator/Xcode fixes it for a bit. I'm going to file a bug and look at the workaround mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351488/543

Answer (score 19):

This error appears to me when I set the colors of anything in the navigation bar to a named color (from Assets). 

I think it is a bug from Apple.

Anyway, you need to change the named color to a **custom color** to avoid this error.

Comment: I observed the same issue in **Xcode 10.2.1**. After seeing your comment I used system Black colour instead of Charcoal colour I defined in assets. And It started working. Thanks 

Comment: That was the problem. Bug is still not solved in xcode 11.2.1.

Comment: Bug is still not solved in xcode 11.3.1. rolling eyes to apple.

Answer (score -2):

Set the **Large title** attribute of Navigation Item to **Never** in the IB