# Why is my app crashing at launch because of an ibShadowedLargeTitleTextAttributes error?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I'm building an app for iOS and using Storyboard for the UI. I am using the traditional `UINavigationController` and it's classes. The title is `prefersLargeTitles` and the title color is a named color I have created. The app is working perfectly fine when I run it on iOS 13, but then when I run it on iOS 12, it crashes on launch and returns the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ibShadowedLargeTitleTextAttributes.'

I have not messed with the `ibShadowedLargeTitleTextAttributes`.

I tried some of the solutions that are provided in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49833678/xcode-error-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-ibshado), however, none of them are working. The problem still occurs even when I delete the navigation controller and when I set the title to standard (not large titles).

I expected the app to run smoothly on all operating systems because I haven't really changed any options in Storyboard. I do experience a pop-up when I launch Xcode though:

> Title: The document "Main.storyboard" had an internal inconsistency that was found and repaired.
>
> Body: This may be due to an SCM operation such as merging. Please save the document to fix the inconsistency.
>
> Details: Multiple resources have the same name: POBlue ← *That is the name of my named color*.

What could the crashing be caused by? Could it be because of the named color or something else I'm not realizing?

Comment: add code snippets, without code its hard to assess the probelm

Comment: @GaneshKarewad I have done everything through Storyboard. Is it okay if I give a screenshot of the Attributes inspector in the Interface Builder? Maybe you can find an issue there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it like this…

Open the .storyboard file in a text editor, and and the bottom you'll see a `<resources>` tag

Within `<resources>`, you'll probably find something like

```
<namedColor name="POBlue">
    <color red="xxx" green="yyy" blue="zzz" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
</namedColor>
<namedColor name="POBlue">
    <color red="xxx" green="yyy" blue="zzz" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
</namedColor>
```

Remove one of the `POBlue` entries and save the file.

Open again in Xcode and the error should be gone

Comment: I have a similar problem with crashing xcode indicating multiple colors with same name.  I tried this fix to delete duplicate colors in main storyboard.  It seemed to fix it but the crashes came back and so did the duplicate colors. I assume it goes back to an earlier file but it kept my other changes? or it created the duplicates again. The crashing must be caused by something else.